# RNPickerSelect trying to display selection from mapping data of objects in an array

Tags: react-native, drop-down-menu

I am using RNPickerSelect from the library "react-native-picker-select", but cant seem to display the selection by mapping objects of an array stored in one of my state.

I tried using the same way to map objects of an array like how I would when I'm trying to display the data by wrapping in simple  components but I'm getting an "Type Error. undefined is not an object (evaluating this.state.selectedItem.label".

I have declared and initialize bankResponseArray : [] within my react native class. And the API call to fetch data was successful, the state "bankResponseArray" was inserted with the data of

```
[
  Object {
"__v": 0,
"_id": "5cb411e06f34961204003b79",
"bank_code": "RHB",
"country": "5cb04a7e23479e39e495f2b6",
"created_date": "2019-04-15T05:08:48.769Z",
"name": "RHB",
"status": true,
},
 Object {
"__v": 0,
"_id": "5cb42d6635ab9132e0e0b994",
"bank_code": "Maybank",
"country": "5cb04a7e23479e39e495f2b6",
"created_date": "2019-04-15T07:06:14.701Z",
"name": "Maybank",
"status": true,
},
Object {
"__v": 0,
"_id": "5cd4e8b0c4022833942eafe0",
"bank_code": "HongLeong",
"country": "5cb04a7e23479e39e495f2b6",
"created_date": "2019-05-10T02:57:52.130Z",
"name": "HongLeong",
"status": true,
},
Object {
"__v": 0,
"_id": "5cd4ee47c4022833942eafe2",
"bank_code": "testbankcode",
"country": "5cbfc9c99b7d064464592948",
"created_date": "2019-05-10T03:21:43.534Z",
"name": "testbank",
"status": true,
```

},
    ]

And below is how my RNPickerSelect component looks like and how I'm trying to map the data from "bankResponseArray" :-

```
<RNPickerSelect
                    placeholder={{}}
                    useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}
                    items={this.state.bankResponseArray.map(obj => 
                      [{
                        label: obj.name,
                        value: obj._id,
                        color: "rgba(77,38,22,1)"
                      }]
                      )}
                    onValueChange={(value, index) => {
                      this.setState({
                        bankID: value
                      });
                    }}
                    onClose={() => {
                      // this._changeGender()
                    }}
                    style={{ ...pickerSelectStyles }}
                    value={this.state.businessType}
                    ref={el => {
                      this.inputRefs.picker = el;
                    }}
                    hideIcon={Platform.OS === "ios" ? false : true}
                    doneText={translate("common_done")}
                    // disabled={!canSubmit}
                  />
```

The expected results were to have the RNPickerSelect display 4 selections which are "RHB, Maybank, HongLeong, testbank". But currently the way I'm trying to map my array to the RNPickerSelect is getting the error of "Type Error. undefined is not an object (evaluating this.state.selectedItem.label".

Comment: Replace the square brackets in the `map` function with parenthesis

Comment: I have replaced square brackets in the map function with parenthesis but still getting the same error

Comment: Can you show the result of the `map` function?

Comment: The result of the map function should make the RNPicker show 4 selections, which labels are RHB, Maybank, HongLeong, and testbank code. and the their value as each of their _id value. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Can you extract the `map` into a separate function and console.log() it?

Comment: Like this: `getItems = () => { const items = this.state.bankResponseArray.map(obj => ({ label: obj.name, value: obj._id, color: 'rgba(77, 38, 22, 1)' })); console.log(items); return items; }`

Comment: And then `items={this.getItems()}`

Answer (score 1):

You should to return an object directly and not an array.

You can use like this:

```
items={this.state.bankResponseArray.map(obj => (
   {
      key: obj._id,
      label: obj.name,
      value: obj._id,
      color: "rgba(77,38,22,1)",
   }))}
```